# Solr schema regex transformer

Tags: indexing, solr

I'm trying to perform internal transformations of fields definded into my solr schema.

I've these 2 fields into my schema.xml :

```
<field name="source_file" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true"/>
<copyField source="source_file_extraction" dest="text"/> :
```

The field *source_file* contains the basename of my indexed docs (example : 1234_helloworld.pdf).
I'd like use a regex to extract some data from this basename (example : extract all digits (\d*) => 1234)} and save this extraction into the field *source_file_extraction*.

For that, I've seen that it could be possible to use regex transformers.
I configure the file solr-data-config.xml as :

```
<dataConfig>
  <document>
    <entity name="source_file_extraction" transformer="RegexTransformer" query="select coll from source_file_extraction">
        <field column="coll" regex=".*?-(\d\d)-.*" sourceColName="source_file"/>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

And I add a requestHandler into the file solrconfig.xml :

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">solr-data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

But it not works.

How to make a simple transformation by regex of a field defined in the schema to another field of the same schema?

Thanks by advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory` filter factory for field     "source_file_extraction"

Update your schema file like below for field `source_file_extraction`

```
<field name="source_file_extraction" type="NameExtractor" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="NameExtractor" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Add copy field from source_file to source_file_extraction

```
<copyField source="source_file" dest="source_file_extraction"/>
```

while token is copied to field `source_file_extraction` it uses filter and keeps only numeric characters from that value and stores.

It doesn't modify `source_file` field value.

Don't forget to restart solr after schema modifications.

Hope this helps,
vinod

Comment: In the indexed fields, the copied content is exactly same as the source. The filters aren't getting reflected. However, I can see the expected changes in the Analysis tab if I do the same for a text. Any idea how to make the changes reflect the changes in the solr core fields as well ? TIA